# Samsung Gear fit 2 widget

Tags: widget, tizen, samsung-gear-fit

Is it possible to develop a widget for Samsung Gear Fit 2?

I've tried [creating-your-first-app/web-widget](http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/creating-your-first-app/web-widget) but I'm not able to 'Run' or 'Debug' it.

This [creating-your-first-app/web](http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/creating-your-first-app/web) works on the device and emulator:

I'm using "Tizen Studio 1.0.1 with IDE installer" 64bit from the Samsung website.

Comment: Can you explain your problem details with some log or error information?

Comment: The log is empty. There's a dialog with partly visible message: The selected target does not support for a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I know, you can't develop widget for Gear fit 2 in Tizen web till now. There're available samples for native widgets but web widgets are only available since **wearable-2.3.2**

Go through the resources you provided in the post carefully. You'll get the applicable platform for Tizen web widget there.

Comment: So it's because of the Gear fit 2 tizen version? I've tried to become information about the tizen version but I can't find them.

Comment: Go to About Device from settings.

Comment: There's just the model: SM-R360 and Softwareversion: R360XXU1BPK6

Comment: Try to run applications of Wearable version 2.3.1 on your Fit2 device. You'll be confirmed about the version then. Moreover, Wearable 2.3.2 runs only in Gear S3 till now. You'll be able to develop such applications on that. For Wearable 2.3.1, you can develop native widget apps.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an app for Gear Fit2 and got the following error when tried uploading it to Samsung App Store:
[image: Error Message]

I've contacted Samsung support asking about the error above, and they basically said that only watch face development is supported for this platform for general public, however they do open the full dev capabilities for their partners.

[image: Samsung's answer]

**UPDATE**

Samsung has currently added support for GearFit2 and GearFit2 Pro, and you can now upload app binaries, not only watch faces to Galaxy App Store. You can also customize the emulator to make sure that it looks like a real GearFit2 watch as I've described here:

[Emulator for Samsung Gear Fit 2 Tizen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883225/emulator-for-samsung-gear-fit-2-tizen/65979214#65979214)