# Emulator for Samsung Gear Fit 2 Tizen

Tags: emulation, tizen, samsung-gear-fit

I would like to develop a web application for Samsung Gear Fit 2 pro, but I have problems with getting an emulator to work. Do you know which emulator I should use?
(None of them scale properly or are circular)

Comment: Have you created any square/rectangular shaped emulator?

Comment: did you try my code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm away during holidays. I will try it as soon as possible and let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till now there is no Emulator on Tizen Studio for Gear Fit series. But you may run your projects on Square Emulator in order to test Fit series projects. 
You can fix the resolution of your project from ***config.xml***.

As the [resolution of Gear Fit 2](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/gear-fit2/) is `216 x 432`, i am setting height and width accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" height="432" width="216" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/XXXX" version="1.0.0"  viewmodes="maximized">
   ........
    <tizen:setting screen-orientation="portrait" context-menu="disable" background-support="disable" encryption="disable" install-location="auto" hwkey-event="enable"/>
</widget>
```

And taking the emulator having resolution `320 x 320` as there are no other square emulator option on the Tizen Studio. Hopefully this technique will solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think this will work, yes :)
And sorry for taking so long to answer.

Comment: You are Welcome :))

Answer (score 1):

You can change the emulator's template properties as shown on the picture below to have exactly the same look and feel as the real watch. Please also note that GearFit2 and Pro are currently supported in Galaxy App Store, so you can submit real apps, not only watch faces.

[image]

Here is the some application running in the emulator created this way

[image]